# HTML TABLE column width not consistent in width

Tags: javascript, html

I have created 2 tabs in which i display 2 tables whose data are loaded from fetch.php. In first tab, i have created 3 dropdown-lists where the last one calls fetch.php. In second tab, i have 1 drop-downlist where it calls fetch.php.

When i open the main html page, i see the content of first tab in which table has specific column width.But when i switch to 2nd tab, the table doesn't have the predefined column width. However, when i penform a search through dropdown list, the width of column is fixed. Why is that happening?

```
    <body>
    <div class="container box">
        <h1 align="center">Αποθήκη</h1>
        <br />
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Γενική</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Συγκεκριμένη</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <!-- Analytical Search -->
            <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <!-- Car Search -->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Αναζήτηση Αυτοκινήτου</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="category_item">Κατασκευαστής</label>
                                <select name="category_item" class="form-control action" id="category_item" data-live-search="true"  title="Επιλέξτε μάρκα"></select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="sub_category_item">Μοντέλο</label>
                                <select name="sub_category_item" id="sub_category_item" class="form-control action" data-live-search="true" title="επιλέξτε μοντέλο"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <div align="center" id="image_result"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <br><br>
                                <label for="sub2_category_item">Έκδοση</label>
                                <select name="sub2_category_item" id="sub2_category_item" class="form-control input-lg" data-live-search="true" title="επιλέξτε έκδοση"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Table with Data -->
                    <br />
                    <table id="manual_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                                <th width="10%">Κατασκευαστής</th>
                                <th width="10%">Κωδικός</th>
                                <th width="75%">Περιγραφή</th>
                                <th width="5%">Φωτογραφία</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                    
            </div>
            
            <!-- Fast Search -->
            <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <!-- Car Search -->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Αναζήτηση Αυτοκινήτου</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
            
                        <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <br>
                                <label for="plates_item">Αρ. Κυκλοφορίας</label>
                                <select name="plates_item" id="plates_item" class="form-control input-lg" data-live-search="true" title="επιλέξτε πινακίδα"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Table with Data -->
                    <br />
                    <table id="automatic_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="10%">Κατασκευαστής</th>
                                <th width="10%">Κωδικός</th>
                                <th width="75%">Περιγραφή</th>
                                <th width="5%">Φωτογραφία</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                    

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The problematic table has id "automatic_data".

```
  $(document).on('change', '#sub2_category_item', function(){
   var filter_part_id = $('#sub2_category_item').val();
   $('#manual_data').DataTable().destroy();
   fill_datatable(filter_part_id);
  });

  $(document).on('change', '#plates_item', function(){
    var filter_part_id = $('#plates_item').val();
    $('#automatic_data').DataTable().destroy();
    fill_datatable2(filter_part_id);
  });

    fill_datatable();
    fill_datatable2();

    function fill_datatable(filter_part_id = '')
   {
     var dataManual = $('#manual_data').DataTable({
     "processing":true,
     "serverSide":true,
     "order":[],
     "ajax":{
         url:"actions/fetch.php",
         type:"POST",
         data:{filter_part_id:filter_part_id}
     }

  });

 }

 function fill_datatable2(filter_part_id = '')
 {
    var dataAutomatic = $('#automatic_data').DataTable({
       "processing":true,
       "serverSide":true,
       "order":[],
       "ajax":{
          url:"actions/fetch.php",
          type:"POST",
          data:{filter_part_id:filter_part_id}
       }

   });

}
```

Any idea? Do you see the cause of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that since the second tab is not active when the page loads, maybe the table may not be fully rendered until it's clicked on.

Have you tried to trigger a resize event on the window object when the second tab is clicked to force the table to redraw and inherit the column widths ?

```
$('a[href="#menu1"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(){
  $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```